# Can't connect to remote debug server with pydevd-pycharm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker

I have a Django project that I deploy with docker. I want to debug the project with `Python Remote Debug`. This I how I configured it according to the https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html

[image]

Afterwards I launched the debugger and it said:

```
Use the following code to connect to the debugger:
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=3000, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
Waiting for process connection...
```

[image]

Afterwards I coppied the code to `__main__` in `manage.py`

[image]

Btw. Puting above code to some `views` instead manage.py dint help either

Next I launched by docker with `docker-compose up -d proj` command

After a while I saw logs from my container that says that:

```
Could not connect to localhost: 3000
NoneType: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 93, in sentry_patched_wsgi_handler
    environ, start_response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/wsgi.py", line 69, in __call__
    rv = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    return SentryWsgiMiddleware(lambda *a, **kw: old_app(self, *a, **kw))(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 112, in sentry_patched_get_response
    return old_get_response(self, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/xwing/middleware.py", line 21, in middleware
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/cards/views.py", line 52, in version
    return Response({'version': get_newest_version()})
  File "/app/cards/queries.py", line 76, in get_newest_version
    pydevd_pycharm.settrace('localhost', port=8080, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1282, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1327, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 364, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 568, in start_client
    sys.exit(1) #TODO: is it safe?
SystemExit: 1
```

So far I tried to run the debug server on differet ports like 0.0.0.0:8000, localhost:8000. But It didn't help. I took another project does does require docker to work, and everything worked find. It seems that there is some problem with a docker. Any ideas? I have no idea why I does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never had done this, but it looks like the part '0.0.0.0' is the address to the machine where Pycharm is running.

You have to set the IP of your machine. May it will be also successful to run your container in network mode "host" (because 0.0.0.0 refers to inside the container)

May you find also useful:

- A very good post over host networking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/10962269
- The documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help anyone but in my case it turned out I forgot that docker on mac OS uses host.docker.internal.

So I set :

```
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('host.docker.internal', port=YOUR_PORT, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

and then clicked on edit configuration => python debug server :

```
host : host.docker.internal
port YOUR_PORT
```

Don't forget the path mappings, (access your docker and see where you can find exactly the same folders as your root, and don't forget to put the absolute path of your root, something like this in my case /Users/UserName/Repo/Your_root= /app/src)

And it worked !

It turns out the port can be anything as long as it doesn't collide with an existing port (be careful, the port in edit configuration and settrace have to match)